# Child gridview update event

Tags: asp.net, gridview, webforms

I have problem regarding child gridview (gridview inside ListView), so far i solved the databind and the the Delete command , but i couldn't figure out the Edut Mode ( i click the image button) but the GV doesn't go to edit mode the codes are as follows: thanks in advance

Page mark-up:

EditItemTemplate

```
 <asp:ImageButton ID="imgbUpdate" runat="server" CommandName="Update" Text="Update" ImageUrl="~/Images/save_icon_mono.gif" CausesValidation="true" ValidationGroup="vgrpSaveContact"/>
 <asp:ImageButton ID="imgbCancel" runat="server" CommandName="Cancel" Text="Cancel" ImageUrl="~/Images/undo_icon_mono.gif" CausesValidation="false"/>
```

EditItemTemplate

```
  <ItemTemplate>
    <table>
     <tr>
       <td> <asp:ImageButton ID="imgbEdit" runat="server" CommandName="Edit" Text="Edit" ImageUrl="~/Images/edit_icon_mono.gif" />
       </td>
       <td> <asp:ImageButton ID="imgbDelete" runat="server" CommandName="Delete" Text="Delete"  ImageUrl="~/Images/delete_icon_mono.gif"  ToolTip="Delete"/>
       </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
  </ItemTemplate>
```

Code VB.NET

```
  Protected Sub gvSorties_RowUpdating(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As GridViewUpdateEventArgs)

    Dim connString As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("MoyensAeriensConnectionString").ConnectionString

    Dim gvTemp As GridView = DirectCast(sender, GridView)
    gvUniqueID = gvTemp.UniqueID
    'Get the value  

    Dim strSortieID As String = DirectCast(gvTemp.Rows(e.RowIndex).FindControl("lblSortieID"), Label).Text
    Using conn As New SqlConnection
        conn.ConnectionString = connString
        conn.Open()

        Try

            Dim strSQL As String = ""
            Dim dsTemp As New SqlDataSource()
            dsTemp.ConnectionString = connString

            'Get the values stored in the text boxes
            Dim strMissionNo As String = DirectCast(gvTemp.Rows(e.RowIndex).FindControl("txtMissionNo"), TextBox).Text
            Dim strCaptain As String = DirectCast(gvTemp.Rows(e.RowIndex).FindControl("txtCaptain"), TextBox).Text
            Dim strCrew As String = DirectCast(gvTemp.Rows(e.RowIndex).FindControl("txtCrew"), TextBox).Text
            Dim strFuel As String = DirectCast(gvTemp.Rows(e.RowIndex).FindControl("txtFuel"), TextBox).Text

            'Prepare the Update Command of the DataSource control
            strSQL = "UPDATE Sortie set MissionNo = '" & strMissionNo & "'" & ",Captain = " & strCaptain & "" & ",Crew = '" & strCrew & "'" & ",Fuel = '" & strFuel & "'" & " WHERE SortieID = " & strSortieID
            dsTemp.UpdateCommand = strSQL
            dsTemp.Update()

            'Reset Edit Index
            gvEditIndex = -1

            lvODV.DataBind()
            conn.Close()
        Catch
        End Try
    End Using
End Sub
```

Many thanks to every one

Comment: Does your Webbrowser (IE) generate some kind of javascript error?

Comment: Webbrowser doesn't (IE) generate any kind of javascript error

Comment: Dows the debugger reach the gvSorties_RowUpdating method? I had a similar problem using ImageButtons. Have you tried to replace them with LinkButtons (with an image inside) ?